# Using Boot Strap To Insert New Rows In Comment Section (Python - Django)

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

**Original Question**

I tried to use `<div class="row">`after looking at the Bootstrap material but the comments still appeared to be rendering in a series of columns and not rows.

[image]

```
<article class="media content-section">
        <!-- comments -->
         <h2>{{ comments.count }} Comments</h2>
        {% for comment in comments %}

          <div class="row">
            <div class="media-body ">
                <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ comment.name }}</a>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ comment.created_on|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
            </div>

            <p class="article-content">{{ comment.body  }}</p>
          </div>

    {% endfor %}
```

**Update 1**

I tried col-md-12 and col-12 but neither worked unfortunately.

[image]

[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="media-body ">
          <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ comment.name }}</a>
          <small class="text-muted">{{ comment.created_on|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
      </div>

      <p class="article-content">{{ comment.body  }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Update 2**

I tried to combine the media and col classes together but that didn't achieve my desired results.

[image]

[image]

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="media col-12">
          <div class="media-body ">
              <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ comment.name }}</a>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ comment.created_on|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
          </div>

          <p class="article-content">{{ comment.body  }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Update 3**

I want every individual comment to be on its own line. Like you see on YouTube, FB, Agoda etc. The screen shot shows how I want the comments to be laid out - 
https://cdn3.f-cdn.com/contestentries/1389606/26048282/5b6c92cc39097_thumb900.jpg.

**Update 4**

After a few experiments I ended up using this code.

[image]

```
<article class="media content-section">
        <!-- comments -->
         <h3>{{ comments.count }} Comments</h3>

  </article>


    <!-- comments -->


    {% for comment in comments %}
    <article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
        <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ comment.name }}</a>
        <small class="text-muted">{{ comment.created_on|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h2 class="article-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body ">
      <p class="article-content">{{ comment.body  }}</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    </article>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: too many images, hard to understand the question  and update will comes after the question not before the question

Comment: please share what you want image and what you got image only.

Comment: I want every individual comment to be on its own line. Like you see on YouTube, FB, Agoda etc. The screen shot shows how I want the comments to be laid out.

Comment: https://cdn3.f-cdn.com/contestentries/1389606/26048282/5b6c92cc39097_thumb900.jpg

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes I think so. I now have a new challenge I am trying to figure out.

Comment: ok so please answer your question and make it as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your code with `col` inside `.row` class. Example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="media-body ">
            <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ comment.name }}</a>
            <small class="text-muted">{{ comment.created_on|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
        </div>

        <p class="article-content">{{ comment.body  }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

More on grid system: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: Please, try to add `media` class near `col` class

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to do this:

```
<article class="media content-section">
     <!-- comments -->
     <div class="row">
         <h2>{{ comments.count }} Comments</h2>
     <div/>

     <div class="row">
     {% for comment in comments %}
         <div class="row">
             <div class="media-body ">
                 <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ comment.name }}</a>
                 <small class="text-muted">{{ comment.created_on|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
             </div>
             <p class="article-content">{{ comment.body  }}</p>
         </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div/>
<div/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out the answer and put it at the bottom of my original post.